# What do you call someone who thinks something someone said is always directed at them?

Tags: vocabulary

Like the title says, I'm trying to find the word that is used to describe a person who thinks things are always directed towards them even if its being talked about in a general way.

Comment: egotist? politician? paranoid?

Comment: .self-centered.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me I would call them 
Paranoid!!!

> **Paranoid**
>   feeling extremely nervous and worried because you believe that other people do not like you or are trying to harm you:
>   *He started feeling paranoid and was convinced his boss was going to fire him.*
>   http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paranoid

Comment: But it's not really that type of thinking things are directed. Let me give an example. There is an emo person around and someone makes a joke about suicide. The emo then assumes that he is talking about him/herself and gets offended by it, but may or may not mention to the person that they were offended

Comment: @AnonymousGuest you should add your example to your question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/224949)

Comment: @Skooba It technically does provide an answer, just an incorrect and poor one.

Comment: @Stepheninsf I added a dictionary definition to back up your answer as I think it's indeed a suitable word here.

Answer (score 1):

1. > **touchy**
   >   *adjective* \ˈtə-chē\
   >
   > marked by readiness to take offense on slight provocation
   >
   > *he's a little touchy about his past*
   >   --[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touchy)
2. > **prickly**
   >   easily irritated
   >
   > *had a prickly disposition*